# How can i upload and set images through App in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, image, xamarin, file-upload

I am creating an App where i want the users to upload the pictures themselves(like their display pictures), But i have no idea to do it. I want to achieve the task for Android and IOS in Xamarin. From this code below i am only able to source to images which are present in Resources.

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: You could use the `FileUploaderPlugin` to upload files(like image) . Check https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin .